# Get SQL code to generate the schema for an existing database in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Given an existing database in PostgreSQL, I want to get the required SQL code to generate an identical database with no records.

Is there any easy way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html) command to do that. The option `-s` dumps only the schema and no data from the database.